# Javascript + HTML table calculations

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I am fairly new to Javascript so I am asking for a help.
So I have an html table which looks like this:
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoE7I.jpg)

And I want to calculate how much time for example task spends on Johns side and how much time tasks spends on other side.

Date format is Month/Day/Year!

So if we take first two entries then John gave a task to Adam at 01/06/2016 but then John got the task back only on 02/07/2016 so what I want now is to perform a calculation and get the days it spent on other side and put it in an array or list so after all calculations have been made we have an array containing the time that was on other side and the time that the task was on Johns side.

How far am I ?

So I am just trying to understand the concept of how javascript grabs table objects a bit complicated, but it's alright.

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
var greeting1 ="john";
var x = document.getElementById("myTable").rows[4].cells;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x[1].innerHTML 
var y = document.getElementById("myTable").rows[2].cells;
document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = y[1].innerHTML 
if (x[1].innerHTML === greeting1){
    greeting ="Got it";

} else {
    greeting = "Didnt get it ";
}
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = greeting;
}
</script>
```

I am able to grab an output the content of cell and perform simple if/else statement. Need advices on how to perform while/for loops to be able to achieve what I want.

Looking forward for your suggestions Thanks!

Comment: I don't really understand your table. Is every row talking about the same task ? How can John sends the task 5 times in a row and not receive any between those sends ?

Comment: Yes the task is one but I have retrieved the table from database and as you see the output has duplicate entries, thats another issue i will work on to clear duplicate entries, but the task is one yes!

Comment: Updated my table removed duplicates!

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get how can John receive the same task multiple times from 2 different person while he didn't send one between

Comment: if you receive the content from a database, why do you render it in a table first and then read out the table again to process the data? Do you have access to the data before it was rendered to HTML?

Comment: It is for example a reminder that other person sends to John saying  you still have not checked the task etc.

Comment: I have data in csv then I run script to turn it into html for better look , do you think it might be easier to perform calculations while the output is in csv?

Comment: yes, it totally makes sense to process the data inbetween those steps. So you could read out the data from the csv into a javaScript data-structure (e.g and array of objects: [{first_row: "..", second_row: "...", date: ".."}, ...] ) From this you can do several things now: render an html table (this is just a visualization, usually not meant for further processings). As well as: Do further calculations with the data.

Comment: Okey thank you very much Anton , will do that!

Comment: sorry, there's something wrong/misleading in my comment, I cannot change it anymore: [{from: "John", to: "Adam", date: ".."}, {from: "Thomas", to: "Jenny", date: ".."}, ...] is a better example, certainly "first_row" does not make sense, I rather meant "first_column"...

Comment: No worries I understand what you meant ,if I will have any sorts of trouble I will try to contact you!

Comment: sure, don't hesitate to do so..